# Integrating Flink Kafka with schema registry

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink, avro, flink-streaming, confluent-schema-registry

We are using a confluent Platform for Kafka deployment. We are using a schema registry for storing schema. Is it possible to integrate schema registry with flink? How to read the data in AVRO format from confluent platform?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These classes are designed to meet this need

- [`ConfluentRegistryAvroSerializationSchema`](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/api/java/org/apache/flink/formats/avro/registry/confluent/ConfluentRegistryAvroSerializationSchema.html)
- [`ConfluentRegistryAvroDeserializationSchema`](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/api/java/org/apache/flink/formats/avro/registry/confluent/ConfluentRegistryAvroDeserializationSchema.html)

See the linked JavaDoc for more info on the classes.

Each can be provided to the [Kafka Connector](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.15/docs/connectors/datastream/kafka/) via the respective serialization method arguments.

[Flink SQL](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.15/docs/connectors/table/formats/avro-confluent/) can also be used.