# Can Apache Flink deserialize KafkaSource Stream with Avro in Java?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-flink, avro

I want to deserialize a KafkaSource Stream with Avro in Flink.

Looking into the Flink documentation I found the following code:

```
KafkaSource<String> source = KafkaSource.<String>builder()
                .setBootstrapServers(BOOTSTRAP_SERVER)
                .setTopics(TOPIC)
                .setGroupId(CONSUMER_GROUP)
                .setStartingOffsets(OffsetsInitializer.earliest())
                .setDeserializer(new SimpleStringSchema())
                .build();
```

I wondered if it was possible to change the `new SimpleStringSchema` into an Avro Deserializer and if yes how?

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72656077/integrating-flink-kafka-with-schema-registry

Answer (score 0):

Use the AvroDeserializationSchema from flink-avro; there are static methods to create a schema from either an Avro schema to read generic records, or from class for specific records.

Comment: when i try to use AvroDeserializationSchema i get the following warning from intellij: 'AvroDeserializationSchema(java.lang.Class, org.apache.avro.Schema)' is not public in 'org.apache.flink.formats.avro.AvroDeserializationSchema'. Cannot be accessed from outside package

Comment: Use the static methods forGeneric/forSpecific, not the constructor.